# how to change image by a button click

Tags: c#, .net, avaloniaui, avalonia

I have a grid of buttons, each associated with an image of a playing card. When a button (representing a card) is clicked, the image of that card should change to a different image, indicating a "reload" effect. Despite implementing the code, I am encountering crashes and need guidance on troubleshooting and resolving the issue. The goal is to achieve a smooth image change upon button clicks without encountering crashes.

```
`<Window xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:vm="using:AvaloniaApplication2.ViewModels"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d" Width="320" d:DesignWidth="320" d:DesignHeight="450"
        x:Class="AvaloniaApplication2.Views.MainWindow"
        x:DataType="vm:MainWindowViewModel"
        Icon="/Assets/avalonia-logo.ico"
        Title="AvaloniaApplication2">

    <Design.DataContext>
        <!-- This only sets the DataContext for the previewer in an IDE,
             to set the actual DataContext for runtime, set the DataContext property in code (look at App.axaml.cs) -->
        <vm:MainWindowViewModel/>
    </Design.DataContext>

    <Grid Name="Grid">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <!-- <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/> -->
            <!-- <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/> -->
            <!-- <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/> -->
            <!-- <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/> -->
            <!-- <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/> -->
            <!-- <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/> -->
            <!-- <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/> -->
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <!-- <Button> -->
        <!--     <Image Source="/Assets/Images/c9.png" /> -->
        <!-- </Button> -->
        
        <Button Click="Button_OnClick">
            <Image Name="Button1Image" Source="/Assets/Images/c9.png" />
        </Button>
        
        <Button Grid.Row="1">
            <Image Source="/Assets/Images/крести_10.png" />
        </Button>

        <Button Grid.Row="2">
            <Image Source="/Assets/Images/крести_j.png" />
        </Button>
        
        <Button Grid.Row="3">
            <Image Source="/Assets/Images/крести_q.png" />
        </Button>
                
        <Button Grid.Row="4">
            <Image Source="/Assets/Images/крести_k.png" />
        </Button>
        
        <Button Grid.Row="5">
            <Image Source="/Assets/Images/крести_а.png" />
        </Button>
        
        <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">
            <Image Source="/Assets/Images/буби_9.png" />
        </Button>
        
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
            <Image Source="/Assets/Images/буби_10.png" />
        </Button>
        
        <Button Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1">
            <Image Source="/Assets/Images/буби_j.png" />
        </Button>
        
        <Button Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1">
            <Image Source="/Assets/Images/буби_q.png" />
        </Button>
        
        <Button Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1">
            <Image Source="/Assets/Images/буби_k.png" />
        </Button>
        
        <Button Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1">
            <Image Source="/Assets/Images/буби_а.png" />
        </Button>
        
        <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2">
            <Image Source="/Assets/Images/чирви_9.png" />
        </Button>
        
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2">
            <Image Source="/Assets/Images/чирви_10.png" />
        </Button>
        
        <Button Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2">
            <Image Source="/Assets/Images/чирви_j.png" />
        </Button>
        
        <Button Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2">
            <Image Source="/Assets/Images/чирви_q.png" />
        </Button>
        
        <Button Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="2">
            <Image Source="/Assets/Images/чирви_k.png" />
        </Button>
        
        <Button Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="2">
            <Image Source="/Assets/Images/чирви_а.png" />
        </Button>
        
        <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3">
            <Image Source="/Assets/Images/пики_9.png" />
        </Button>
        
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3">
            <Image Source="/Assets/Images/пики_10.png" />
        </Button>
        
        <Button Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3">
            <Image Source="/Assets/Images/пики_j.png" />
        </Button>
        
        <Button Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="3">
            <Image Source="/Assets/Images/пики_q.png" />
        </Button>
        
        <Button Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="3">
            <Image Source="/Assets/Images/пики_k.png" />
        </Button>
        
        <Button Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="3">
            <Image Source="/Assets/Images/пики_а.png" />
        </Button>
        
    </Grid>

</Window>`
```

```
using System.Linq;
using Avalonia.Controls;
using Avalonia.Interactivity;
using Avalonia.Markup.Xaml;
using Avalonia.Media.Imaging;

namespace AvaloniaApplication2.Views;

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private Image _button1Image;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        AvaloniaXamlLoader.Load(this);
        _button1Image = this.FindControl<Image>("Button1Image");
    }


    private void Button_OnClick(object? sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _button1Image.Source = new Bitmap("/Assets/Images/reload.png"); 
    }
}
```

I attempted to change the image displayed on a button click in my Avalonia UI application. I expected the image of the clicked button (representing a playing card) to smoothly transition to a new image (a "reload" effect) without any crashes. However, despite my efforts, the application crashed, and I couldn't achieve the desired behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues once and it is actually not as easy as it sounds, you can find entire discussion about it and possible solutions on [github](https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/issues/3860). In my case I went with a simple workaround and I have placed two images on the top of each other and I played with their visibility.

```
<Button>
   <Image Source="/Assets/Images/1.png" />
   <Image Source="/Assets/Images/2.png" IsVisible="False"/>
</Button>
```

Then whenever you click a button you can just invert their `IsVisible` property. If you want the smooth transition you could change `Opacity` instead and add an animation or use the `Carousel` control.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are doing, what I see could be improved with best practices, but I think that is for learning purposes. The quick solution would be this.

Add Click="Button_OnClick" to all buttons to dispatch the event.